# Is the bitdigger chrome extension fraud?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, mining-pools, javascript

Today, while I was watching a video on YouTube, I found the video on the [bitdigger extension](http://bitdigger.io/69f04c5c904b4e2b3122f3e8582b50f5e4f4729e) that mine bitcoins with chrome browser. I just want to know if it is fraud or legit? Is it possible to mine via JavaScript?

**Edit:** My computer is always turn on, let's say at least 20h in a day. Is it bad if I leave bitdigger run in a part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want to know is it fraud or legit?

I have never used it. But: It's not profitable. Big mining pools use ASICs to mine bitcoins. In the past, people used GPU. But mining in your browser means mining with CPU which is completly unprofitable as you will probably never be the first one with a hash of 20 zeros but you'll waste energy.

> Is it possible mining via Javascript?

Yes. There is [Coinhive](https://coinhive.com/). They offer a script you can implement in your website. And if a user with activated Javascript visits this site, the mining starts. But it's not bitcoin what is mined. It's [Monero](https://getmonero.org/) because it's much more profitable.

Answer (score 1):

no, this is totally fake.it only generate number not generate satoshi because bitcoin mining process used internet to create pool, but in bitdigger if you disable internet from router then mining process not stop, so i think this totally fake. don't install it...

Answer (score 0):

..This is very imformative and at the same time very disappointing for me, cause im a user of bitdigger for almost three months. that's why i shifted to pool mining. it's really fishy right now for me cause i checked their site and Monero (XMR) is the only one they "include" in their offers and i can't see any Bitcoin either.

Comment: I checked bitdigger extension.. and gauss what? they mined Monero. If bitdigger is not fraud then I think after you have mined 0.005xmr (as mentioned in extension) and they convert XMR into BTC and maybe transfer to your given wallet.